# How can get the histogram from each rgb channel in a picture?

Tags: python

I'm trying some stuff on the Lena testing picture, one of which is plotting the each rgb histogram independently but for some reason it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
from skimage import io, color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Charger l'image Lena
X = io.imread('lena.png')
fig, (ax0, ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3)
rgb=[]
for i in range(3):
    rgb.append(X[:,:,i])
ax0.imshow(plt.hist(rgb[0]))
ax1.imshow(plt.hist(rgb[1]))
ax2.imshow(plt.hist(rgb[2]))
```

Comment: When you say it’s not working, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your solution, you are missing the `ply.show()` at the end.

You could also do the following using `open-cv`:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
for i, col in enumerate(['b', 'g', 'r']):
    hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [i], None, [256], [0, 256])
    plt.plot(hist, color = col)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
    
plt.show()
```

This will plot the histogram as continues line on top of each other with different color representing each channel, but you can use the same logic to separate the plots and show discrete histrogram.